# Páginas do Laravel 5.2 redirecionando no POST sem mostrar erros de validação

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

No laravel 5 sempre quando tento enviar um post para salvar ou editar os dados, ocorre um redirecionamento em todas as requisições com o status 302 .

Isso está ocorrendo em qualquer página do sistema em que eu faço um `POST` para inserir os dados no banco.

Eu estou utilizando os `Requests` personalizados do `Laravel` para poder validar os dados, porém nenhum erro de validação está sendo exibido.

Alguém sabe me falar o que pode ocasionar isso no laravel 5?

segue o código da minha rota.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function(){

   Route::any('usuario/salvar','UsuarioController@anySalvar');

});
```

Nos testes que fiz o método é acessado, porém tem o redirecionamento e não exibe erros nenhum. Estou usando `Session Flash` e as validação do `Laravel`, que deveria retornar os erros na view dentro da variável `$errors`, mas não são exibidas nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Manda o erro aí. Por número não sei qual é. Tem a ver com o CSFR Token ?

Comment: 302 é "movida temporariamente" não conheço laravel o suficiente pra responder o pq eles usam esse código pra responder uma requisição.

Comment: Coloque o conteudo de routes e do teu controlador, pode ser também que ao acessar `usuario/salvar` ele direcione para `usuario/salvar/` e por isso você vê esta mensagem, recomendo que leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ele não colocou os detalhes do erro. Eu trabalho junto com ele, e dei um tapa na pergunta, para descrever melhor o problema

Comment: @WallaceMaxters aproveita que você esta perto dele e da um tapa na cabeça dele pra ele ler o MCVE ... Brincadeira :p --- Poh legal saber que vocês trabalham juntos.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `Laravel 5.2`, todas as rotas devem passar pelo grupo de middleware chamado `web`.

O que ocorre é que, em algumas releases do `Laravel 5.2`, as configurações do `RouteServiceProvider` está da seguinte forma:

```
  /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web'], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
```

Observe que ali já vem declarado que todas as rotas que você criar dentro de `Http/routes.php` terão as configurações definidas no `$router->group`. No seu caso, verificamos que está assim, então quando você fez a sua declaração `['middleware' => ['web','auth']`, você está fazendo com que esse `middleware` seja processado novamente.

Por incrível que parece, o grupo de Middleware `web` é responsável pelo pré-processamento da sessão.

Quando você fala a respeito de "nenhum erro está sendo exibido", provavelmente está falando dos erros de validações, que usam o `MessageBag`, que por sua vez usam o `Session Flash`.

O `Flash` é criado apenas uma vez, sendo que, quando é acessado, o mesmo é removido. Se você chama o `middleware` duas vezes por causa da redeclaração, é óbvio que na segunda chamada o `Session Flash` deixará de existir.

Sendo assim, a solução para o seu problema é simplesmente remover `web` do seu `array`, ficando assim:

```
['middleware' => ['auth']
```

Com isso conseguimos resolver o problema.

Vale ressaltar que em algumas versões do `Laravel 5.2`, esse método não vem com o middleware web, sendo necessário adicionar  ou na declaração do Grupo de rotas ou na declaração do RouteServiceProvider.

No meu projeto por exemplo, está dessa forma:

```
    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Em qual release em específico ocorreu essa alteração?

Comment: @gmsantos sinceramente, eu não sei. Mas eu baixei o laravel 5.2 em casa e outra vez aqui na empresa. Reparei que mesmo os dois sendo 5.2, houve diferença