# Não consigo pegar os dados de quem esta logado

Tags: laravel-5

Estou com uma duvida, gostaria de recuperar os dados de que esta logado sem ter que passar pela view, e utilizar eles em qualquer view, então resolvi fazer na controller `__construct` mais o laravel não deixa eu pegar os dados do usuario.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\User;
use app\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->projects = Auth::user()->id;

            return $next($request);
        });

        $projects = $request->user();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Seu problema pode ser similar a esse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127178/p%C3%A1ginas-do-laravel-5-2-redirecionando-no-post-sem-mostrar-erros-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o/127187#127187

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) para adicionar uma variável global, que todos as views do laravel irão herdar.

Você precisa definir isso no método `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::register` da sua aplicação:

```
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        $view['USUARIO'] = auth()->user();
    });
```

No exemplo acima, todas as suas views teriam por padrão avariável `$USUARIO` contendo os dados do `auth()`.

**Observação**: particularmente gosto de usar variáveis globais para views com nomes em caixa alta, para poder diferenciar das que são passadas por parâmetro da view.